# sql: expected 3 destination arguments in Scan, not 1 in Golang

Tags: sql, sql-server, go

I am writing a generic code to query data from any RDS table. I have gone through many StackOverflow answers but none of it worked for me. I have gone through below links:-

- [panic: sql: expected 1 destination arguments in Scan, not <number> golang, pq, sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117714/panic-sql-expected-1-destination-arguments-in-scan-not-number-golang-pq-s)
- [How to query any table of RDS using Golang SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610203/how-to-query-any-table-of-rds-using-golang-sdk/59613836#59613836)

My first code is

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type BA_Client struct {
    ClientId    int    `json:ClientId;"`
    CompanyName string `json:CompanyName;"`
    CreateDate  string `json:CreateDate;"`
}

func main() {

    conn, _ := getConnection() // Det database connection

    query := `select * from IMBookingApp.dbo.BA_Client
              ORDER BY
                ClientId ASC
              OFFSET 56 ROWS
              FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY ;`

    var p []byte
    err := conn.QueryRow(query).Scan(&p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error1", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Data:", p)

    var m BA_Client
    err = json.Unmarshal(p, &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error2", err)
    }

}
```

My second code is

```
conn, _ := getConnection()
query := `select * from IMBookingApp.dbo.BA_Client__c
          ORDER BY
            ClientId__c ASC
          OFFSET 56 ROWS
          FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY ;`

rows, err := conn.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:")
    log.Fatal(err)
}

println("rows", rows)

defer rows.Close()

columns, err := rows.Columns()
fmt.Println("columns", columns)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for rows.Next() {
    receiver := make([]*string, len(columns))

    err := rows.Scan(&receiver )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading rows: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Data:", p)

    fmt.Println("receiver", receiver)
}
```

With both the codes, I am getting the same error as below

```
sql: expected 3 destination arguments in Scan, not 1
```

Can it be because I am using SQL Server and not MySQL? Appreciate if anyone can help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a slice of inputs for your row scan, use the variadic 3-dots notation `...` to convert the slice into individual parameters, like so:

```
err := rows.Scan(receiver...)
```

Your (three in this case) columns, using the variadic arguments will effectively expand like so:

```
// len(receiver) == 3
err := rows.Scan(receiver[0], receiver[1], receiver[2])
```

***EDIT***:

SQL Scan method parameter values must be of type `interface{}`. So we need an intermediate slice. For example:

```
is := make([]interface{}, len(receiver))
for i := range is {
    is[i] = receiver[i]

    // each is[i] will be of type interface{} - compatible with Scan()
    // using the underlying concrete `*string` values from `receiver`
}

// ...

err := rows.Scan(is...)

// `receiver` will contain the actual `*string` typed items
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It is giving me this error - `cannot use receiver (type []*string) as type []interface {} in argument to rows.Scan`

Comment: @RahulSatal updated answer to include intermediate `interface{}` slice step.

Comment: @colnimator Now I am getting another error - `Error reading rows: sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "ClientId": destination not a pointer` where `ClientId` is the name of my table's first column.  You can see the code here - https://play.golang.org/p/vssYYgDA0gs

Comment: Your posted question used `receiver := make([]*string, len(columns))` - so that is a pointer. Your playground link is using a `[]string` i.e. a non-pointer. So either use the pointer backing-slice. Or change my line above to `is[i] = &receiver[i]`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot, @Colminator. I was struggling on this for 3 days:)

Comment: I am getting the error - `Scan error on column index 1, name "PhoneExtension": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *string` for the above code while handling the `NULL` fields. The link to the code is - https://play.golang.org/p/IpxI1HPS6OS. How we can update the above code to add `sql.NullString`

Comment: You could use `**string` - to handle `NULL`, but I would recommend using `sql.NullString` to avoid boiler-plate nil checks, so to use that type: `receiver := make([]sql.NullString, len(columns))` combined with `is[i] = &receiver[i]`

Comment: @RahulSatal I do have more generic code to dynamically allocate the required native go type per SQL column type. Perhaps that would be more helpful, as it does not box you into assume the column types are stings only.

Comment: The above solution worked for me. Please share your code too.

Answer (score 0):

try this (no ampersand in front of receiver) for second example:

```
err := rows.Scan(receiver)
```

`receiver` and `*string` are already a reference types. No need to add another reference to it.

Comment: I have tried this too but It is also not working for me. Do you have any other suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

specific field table

```
query := `select * from IMBookingApp.dbo.BA_Client__c
      ORDER BY
        ClientId__c ASC
      OFFSET 56 ROWS
      FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY ;`
```

change to

```
query := `select ClientId, CompanyName, CreateDate   from IMBookingApp.dbo.BA_Client__c
      ORDER BY
        ClientId__c ASC
      OFFSET 56 ROWS
      FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY ;`
```